# passing multiple parameters from php to shell

Tags: php, c++, windows, shell

I want to run .exe (c++) file by php script. I tried very different combinations of exec command, but still my programs returned -2 (argv<6) or array (?), now I tried to use shell_exec

```
<?php

$params = array ('nnn.jpg', 'fff.jp2', '300', '300', '50');
$params_string = implode(" ", $params);

shell_exec('demo.exe '.$params_string);
echo 'demo.exe '.$params_string
?>
```

but it is not working too... I echoed the string I used, and it's just okay

I got it to send parameters properly, but program exits with error caused by write problem. I've changed all perms in target folder to "full control". Maybe there is something with php settings? (xampp on win7 x64)

```
demo.exe nnn.jpg fff.jp2 300 300 50
```

any ideas?

I got it to send parameters properly, but program exits with error caused by write problem. I've changed all perms in target folder to "full control". Maybe there is something with php settings? (xampp on win7 x64)

ERROR: Exception: demo.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `kush.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532-5

but as I said before, all goes well through cmd...

Comment: Do use [`escapeshellarg`](http://www.php.net/escapeshellarg), but otherwise, it should just work, unless that `demo.exe` doesn't understand those args.

Comment: On a side note, 5 args _is_ smaller then 6....

Comment: well, but argv[0] holds info about number of args passed, and it should count it... anyway, when I paste above string into cmd, it works...

Comment: could it be that you don't have file access to 'kush.jpg' from apache/php?  Check the apache userid settings; is it compatible with your file access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was more server issue, dar7yl was almost correct, problem was apache haven't access to imagemagick lib, located in program files... I had to change apache user to my account, and now all works fine ;)